# Entity Framework, random query paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

This is what I want to achieve:

1. I want to query my db to return a list of entities
2. Randomize the list
3. Store the IDS of items received for future queries
4. Run a new query on the same table where the IDs are in the list that I have stored
5. Order by the list that I have stored.

I have managed to achieve step 1, 2, 3, 4 already but step 5 is difficult. Can anyone help me with a query like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4....)
ORDER BY (1,2,3,4....)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT table_name.*
FROM   crazy_sorted_table
       LEFT JOIN
       table_name ON crazy_sorted_table.ID=table_name.ID
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input on this, i now have to translate this into linq to entites or some lambda, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A normal join (equi join) should do the trick , here is sample approach i tested:

```
/**crazyOrder filled 100 rows with random value from 1-250 in Id**/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[crazyOrder] (
[Id]   INT          NOT NULL,
[Area] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
/**Normal order is filled with value from 1-100 sequentially in id**/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[normalOrder] (
[Id]   INT          NOT NULL,
[Name] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

create table #tempOrder
(id int)
insert into #tempOrder
Select top 10 Id
  from crazyOrder
   order by NewID()
go
Select n.*
from normalOrder n
  join #tempOrder t
  on t.id = n.id
```

I was able to retrieve the rows in the same order as in the temp table (i used a data generator for the values)

Comment: Thank you as well, I found an easier way to do this. But I appreciate this very much